# Add Offline Export chart capability in Angular-8

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to add Offline Export chart capability in Angular-8 using below :

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import offlineExporting from "highcharts/modules/offline-exporting"
offlineExporting(Highcharts)

exporting: {
    ...,
    fallbackToExportServer: false
},
```

Reference : [Try to offline exporting to Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878131/try-to-offline-exporting-to-highcharts)

But it does not shows the icon to export , however if I replace '**offline-exporting**' with just '**exporting**' it works fine. However our project runs behind VPN & access to internet is cut off, also '**exporting**' module does a XHR request on internet , which is not allowed in our project due to security concerns. Is there a way around this.

Below is the stackbliz reproduction of the same : https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-yqtwpb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Please let me know there is something different for Angular specific way.

Highchart version in package.json :

**highcharts : '^8.2.0'
highcharts -angular : '^2.8.0',**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the `exporting` module which is also required. After importing the `exporting` module you should be able to export your charts.

```js
import HC_exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
HC_exporting(Highcharts);
...
```

**API references:** 
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export

**Live demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-xhsy4u?file=src/app/app.component.ts